# Dataset manipulation, substitution

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following dataset:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 V6  V7  V8 V9 V10
   1:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
   2:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
   3:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
   4:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
   5:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
  ---                                      
3180:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
3181:  NA  NA 185  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
3182: 151 162 162 157 150 NA 162 162 NA  NA
3183:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
3184: 153  NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA
```

I am trying to replace all the 174's with a 1, and then set everything else equal to 0.
This is my code:

```
sibling=data.table(cbind((data[,'b16aa']),(data[,'b16ba']),(data[,'b16ca']),(data[,'b16da']),(data[,'b16ea']),    (data[,'b16fa']),(data[,'b16ga']),(data[,'b16ha']),(data[,'b16ia']),(data[,'b16ja'])))
sibling[sibling == 174] <-1
```

However the output is:

```
 > sib1
[1] 1
```

This is clearly false, and I am not sure how to set everything else equal to 0.

Comment: You have *not* provided a reproducible example. What is `data`? Your "dataset" has no columns called 'b16aa' or anything like that. If you are using `data.table` and `data` is a `data.table`, then you shoud not be creating sibling the way you are. There are so many things missing and possible problems with your approach as it is.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408642/dataset-manipulation-substitution/16408858#16408858

Answer (score 2):

If `DF` is your data frame then try this:

```
DF[] <- as.numeric(DF == 174 & !is.na(DF))
```

or this non-destructive version which can be assigned to the name you wish:

```
replace(DF, TRUE, as.numeric(DF == 174 & !is.na(DF)))
```

Comment: I want everything in the data table that is equal to 174 to be 1 and everything else go to 0 even the NA's.

Comment: Have added a condition for the `NA` values too now.